# VBA Excel - Add Decimal Places to Integer

Tags: excel, vba

I really hate to ask what I feel like should be able to be resolved by a quick run to a search engine, but I have looked to no avail.

I am extracting some data from a CSV that really should be expressed as a decimal but is not (it should 757.46 not 75746 for example). Using Format(expresion, "Currency"), Format(expression, "Fixed") and so on, does not have the desired effect. The functions just append a decimal point and extra zeroes (75746.00 instead of 757.46). Is there any an easy way to indicate to the Module to take an integer, add a decimal with two numbers to right and variable numbers to the left, and not add anything extra. I am sure there is a way to do this by converting to string, using sub strings and the like, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: format them after you divide by 100

Comment: How are you extracting the data? If you are using the data tab then you get a chance to tell Excel what the decimal separator is: http://superuser.com/questions/385511/easy-way-to-one-off-import-data-with-different-decimal-separator-in-excel

Comment: Without seeing your code or data, it is not possible to give the best solution. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using `Format(expresion, "Currency")` is giving you 75746.00 as the cell, then `Format(expression/100, "Currency")` should give the right result. You would also want to put in a check that expression did not already have a decimal point

Comment: Well, know I feel like a fool. How could I overlook something so simple. Thanks to you and all who offered suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the numbers you've been given by 100 and then formatting as currency should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below, it will loop through the rows and put the orig values from Column A in Column B:

```
Sub ChangeOrigFormat()

Dim lrow As Long

' modify to your last row , or use dynamic last row method
For lrow = 2 To 10

    ' put result on Column B
    With Cells(lrow, 2)
        ' looking in original values in Column A >> modify according to your needs
        .Value = Cells(lrow, 1) / 100
        ' using a decimal with 2 digits after the "."
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With

Next lrow

End Sub
```